# Nanowire Band Structure using Siesta DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, siesta, nanostructures

I'm working with the Siesta DFT software, and managed to reproduce the band structure of bulk Si without any issues. However, when trying the same with a Si nanowire, the band structure looks nowhere near those [published in literature](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1386947705005345?via%3Dihub), and there doesn't seem to be any bandgap either. Has anyone had previous experience with a similar situation?
[image: Relevant figure from the article]

[image: Results from current calculations]

```
SystemName      Si
SystemLabel     Si

NumberOfSpecies         1
NumberOfAtoms           85

%block ChemicalSpeciesLabel
  1  14  Si
%endblock ChemicalSpeciesLabel

LatticeConstant 5.41 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
  16.00  0.00   0.00
   0.00  1.00   0.00
   0.00  0.00  16.00
%endblock LatticeVectors

AtomCoorFormatOut  Ang
AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
35.1650000000 0.0000000000 35.1650000000 1
36.5175000000 1.3525000000 36.5175000000 1
...
51.3950000000 2.7050000000 48.6900000000 1
50.0425000000 1.3525000000 50.0425000000 1
%endblock AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
   1  0   0  0.5
   0  16  0  0.5
   0  0   1  0.5
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack

PAO.BasisSize           DZP
XC.functional           LDA      
XC.authors              CA       
SpinPolarized           .false.  
MeshCutoff              300 Ry   
kgrid_cutoff            100.0 Ang

MD.TypeOfRun       CG               
MD.VariableCell    true             
MD.NumCGsteps      50               
MD.MaxCGDispl      0.1 Bohr         
MD.MaxForceTol     0.01 eV/Ang      
MD.MaxStressTol    0.0001 eV/Ang**3 
%block GeometryConstraints          

%endblock GeometryConstraints

MD.UseSaveXV  true
MaxSCFIterations   100
DM.MixingWeight    0.01
DM.NumberPulay     3
DM.Tolerance       1.d-3
ElectronicTemperature  25 meV
SolutionMethod    diagon

BandLinesScale        pi/a
%block BandLines
1  0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 \Gamma
50 0.0000000000 1.0000000000 0.0000000000 Y
%endblock BandLines

%block WaveFuncKPoints
0.000 0.000 0.000 from 1 to 20
%endblock WaveFuncKPoints
```

Comment: We would need more information, can you show your band structure?  I am assuming the ones in the post are from the literature.

Comment: Hi @TristanMaxson, I have added the results from my calculations as the second image. The band structure is plotted from Gamma (x=0) to increasing K in the direction of the nanowire length.

Comment: Is the structure you are using the exact same one as in the reference you are comparing with? The band structures of nanomaterials can vary widely depending on the details of the structure, for example there exist both metallic and insulating carbon nanotubes.

Comment: The one in the reference has the surface passivated with Hydrogen. However, as far as I found, this passivation is said to reduce the band gap (not eliminate at the considered diameters). And, since I use non passivated nanowires, the band gap should be either higher or at least comparable (I could be wrong as well).

Comment: You will need to ping ProfM for him to be notified of your comment.

Comment: @Tyberius I ended up passivating the surface of the nanowire with Hydrogen. I am not too certain on where I went wrong earlier, but upon passivating the surface, the results are as expected. Also, what is the process of pinging someone? Is there a guide to these tools somewhere? Also thanks for bringing this question back to my attention. I had also missed it due to the high workload.

Comment: Basically you just need to include @username in the comment and you can notify anyone who has already commented on your post. Since you posted this question, you get notified of any comments on it. A [full description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) of comment notifications is given on main Meta. A more [abbreviated description](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5474/what-are-the-rules-for-pinging-someone-in-comments) is available on physics meta. Unfortunately, the guidance for these things is spread out/tough to find at times.

Comment: @Tyberius thanks.

Comment: @ProfM would you please be kind enough to provide any insight if possible. For me, the problem is actually solved because I moved to passivated structures. However for someone else looking into the same scenario, that could be helpful. Also I would like to understand the reasons as well.

Comment: I am not sure what the reason is other than passivating the surface changes the results significantly. Perhaps the dangling bonds without passivation lead to the metallic behavior? Also, I would suggest you write the answer to your own question (allowed) for future reference.

Comment: @ProfM thanks. I'll update this if I find the exact reason for this behavior.

Comment: @PBH Is there any update yet?

Comment: @NikeDattani I passivated the structure to obtain the same one as in literature. However it is still not clear to me why the metallic behavior occurred. It could be the reason mentioned by ProfM in his comment. I didn't write an answer as I am still not completely sure about this.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: How did this go? Have you found an answer now? It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue since it's been there for more than 12 months now! Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani I figured out the answer, but I am not sure if it has the depth to be a complete answer. What happened is that the unpassivated structure had dangling bonds at the surface which caused new energy levels known as surface states [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_states).

Comment: @PBH I think a partial answer would still be useful. My tendency (though you don't necessarily have to do this) is to make answers I'm less confident in or feel are incomplete into Community Wikis, so they can be supplemented if another user comes along that can fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer with complete reasoning behind what had happened. However, I am giving this answer in case someone faces the same situation in the future.

What had happened was, I did not use surface passivated nano-wires. This means that the atoms on the surface of the structure had dangling bonds due to the lack of neighboring atoms. This caused the structures to show surface states of electrons which cause band lines inside the gap of the material. A brief overview of the phenomenon can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_states) and a better insight can be obtained through this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.115417).

In order to avoid this complication (for the case of nanostructures), the best way would be to terminate the surface bonds using hydrogen atoms (Sometimes -OH and -NH3 terminations are also used if I remember correctly).

To do this, I tried a lot of software packages such as [Pymol](https://pymol.org/2/) and [Olex2](https://www.olexsys.org/olex2/) etc, but ended up having issues on the resultant structure near the periodic boundaries. Eventually I used my own code to calculate the number of neighbors and added the H atoms based on that. However this wasn't the most convenient or reliable approach since I had to manually verify every structure before the DFT calculations.